# Why does bluemix seem to hang when the --no-cache option is used to build docker containers?

Tags: caching, containers, pipeline, ibm-cloud

While using the pipeline process to build bluemix docker containers, I have found that the --no-cache option causes the build step to hang/fail.  The log shows that the `ice build --no-cache` command does not succeed because it "could not connect to container cloud service".  I need to use the --no-cache option because my docker build runs a git clone on a second repository.  It is a know limitation that docker will aggressively cache layers and not rerun the git clone.  Thus the build does not have the latest code.

How can I debug the hang condition?  Is there another option to force the git clone in the docker build?  I saw one suggestion to generate a unique script that runs the git clone, but this doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option might just be to raise a support ticket on the matter. http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport